# How can you transfer wireless settings from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, wubi, settings

Wubi did not transfer the wireless settings during the install. How can I transfer them? I DON'T want to install anything, nor retype the information, it's really complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't transfer the wireless settings from windows automatically. Assuming all went OK with your install, boot up ubuntu, click on the wireless icon in the top right, select your network and enter the wireless password. It should only be required once. It is no harder than on windows, indeed it is easier.

Comment: That won't be easy if you need to save of lots of different network passwords for lots of different locations. Typing in 10 different network passwords manually is tedious - I still hope there's a better solution than this.